# How to inject a HttpSession and HttpServletRequest when unit-testing dropwizard in junit5?

Tags: java, unit-testing, dropwizard, junit5

This is very frustrating. I am building an application using dropwizard and testing it with **junit5** and the **dropwizard-testing** module (the junit5 version). Then, I am trying to test a simple endPoint in a resource. The endpoint receives a HttpSession (and the request) but it is always `null`. I have read a lot but I can not find how to inject the session.

This is my Resource:

```
@POST
@Path("/doStuff")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
public String doStuff(@Session HttpSession session
        , @Context HttpServletRequest request) {
     // Do the stuff with the session and the request
}
```

My test is something like this:

```
@ExtendWith(DropwizardExtensionsSupport.class)
class MyResourceTest {
    ResourceExtension resources = ResourceExtension.builder()
        .addResource(new MyResource())
        .build();


    @BeforeEach
    void setup() {
    }

    @Test
    void testDoStuff() {
        Response response = resources.target("/api/doStuff")
            .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
            .accept(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
            .post();
        System.out.println(response);
    }
}
```

I need to manipulate the session and the request by test.  Is it possible? all help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a test container factory.

```
ResourceExtension resources = ResourceExtension.builder()
    .setTestContainerFactory(new GrizzlyWebTestContainerFactory())
    .addResource(new MyResource())
    .build();
```

If you use maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.test-framework.providers</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-test-framework-provider-grizzly2</artifactId>
    <!-- version>${jersey.version}</version -->
    <scope>test</scope>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks. Excuse the long delay. I tried the solution just now... but it gives me a "java.lang.IllegalStateException: InjectionManagerFactory not found" message... no luck for me

Comment: I found that I need to include 'org.glassfish.jersey.inject:jersey-hk2:2.28' but then there is a ArrayStoreException

Answer (score 0):

I had a similiar problem and solved it with a test container factory too. However my approach is different from the one jgl posted earlier.

```
public class SessionRestTest extends JerseyTest {

    @Override
    protected TestContainerFactory getTestContainerFactory() {
        // standard servername and port is localhost:9998
        return new GrizzlyWebTestContainerFactory();
    }

    @Override
    protected DeploymentContext configureDeployment() {
        ResourceConfig config = new ResourceConfig(SessionRest.class);
        return ServletDeploymentContext.forServlet(
                new ServletContainer(config)).build();
    }

    private Response get() {
        return target("/session/logout").request().get();
    }

    @Test
    public void testRedirectURL() {
        Response response = get();
        assertEquals("should return status 200", HttpStatus.OK_200, response.getStatus());
    }

}
```